# MFC programming in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to this MFC stuff, I am working on a project, where i need to use class CFileFind which is in MFC. how can I link to my regular VC++ program to use that class.

I am completely new to MFC, n apologize if there is a mistake.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using Qt instead?

Comment: Have you looked at some tutorial examples from http://www.functionx.com/visualc/ ? Also, it may be advisable to start from creating a project from a MFC project wizard in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use the Windows API directly, via [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx), and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx)?

MFC will add a lot of overhead... if you're just using it for this, it's a waste.  I would only consider MFC if you're planning to write large portions of your application using the whole MFC framework.

That being said, I'd actually recommend avoiding MFC altogether unless you have a reason to use it.  There are many other clean, easy to use frameworks if you need an entire GUI framework, such as Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Include afx.h and look at the general project settings. There should be an option to specify that you want to use MFC either as shared DLL or static library.

What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to make your other program an MFC application, or you'll need to encapsulate the MFC stuff in an MFC DLL and invoke the DLL from your application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the following headers (better in precompiled header like stdafx.h/cpp)

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
```

you should also initialize MFC framework by calling:

```
// initialize MFC and print and error on failure
if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
{
  _tcerr << _T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed") << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If only finding the file is wanted in the application, simply use [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea), [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea), [FindClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findclose) and [PathMatchSpec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmatchspeca) window APIs.  No need to include MFC library for that.  These APIs have better approach than MFC CFileFind and there is no library include overhead.